# Использование BottomSheetBehavior поверх Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-support-library

Есть `layout` и код обработчика. 
`BottomSheetBehavior` не работает. Убираем фрагмент карты, `bottomSheetBehavior` работает.
Как использовать `BottomSheetBehavior` совместно с картой?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="clickme" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/vBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ccff0000"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

и код в `onCreate`

```
        findViewById(R.id.btClick).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view = findViewById(R.id.vBottom);
            BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view);
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });
```

Comment: А просто фрагмент с картой работает ли?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид да, вполне. ссылка на библиотеку добавлена в build.gradle, api key указан в meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему костылем:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
  <Fragment/><!--карта-->
  <CoordinatorLayout id1>
    <NestedScrollView id2 BottomSheetBehavior/>
  </CoordinatorLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

**id1**—контейнер для **View id2** с `BottomSheetBehavior`.
**id1** перехватывает тач, поэтому необходимо менять его видимость при вызове и сокрытии `BottomSheetBehavior`.

Так можно вызывать `BottomSheetBehavior` с помощью, например, кнопки.
Однако, невозможно отображать его скроллом от нижней стороны экрана.